# My input is coming different in my program

Tags: java, io

The problem is that my input is 2, but according to my program it is 50. There is something wrong which I cannot understand. Here my aim is to make a contacts application where a user can keep on adding his/her contacts and all is saved and organized in the hash map.

For testers in the field of IO, I have been working with only the method `contactList()`. So at the moment other methods have not a lot of functionality.

```
 package examples.hash.hashmap.IOintegration;
   import java.util.HashMap;
   import java.io.*;
   public class Contacts{
        /*Aim:
            *Takes input from the user to add, remove or read a contact's number
            *It also can show you all the contacts the user has added
            *What's more it is finally integrated with IO!! 
         */
        //Initializing some very crucial variables 
        HashMap contacts = new HashMap();
        InputStreamReader keyboardMethod = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
        BufferedReader readerMethod = new BufferedReader(keyboardMethod);
        public void contactList(){
            System.out.println(contacts.entrySet());
        }
         public void addContact(){
            System.out.println("Give contacts name");
        }
        public void removeContact(){}
        public int getNumber(){
            return 1;
        }
        public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException{
            InputStreamReader keyboardOption = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
            BufferedReader readerOption = new BufferedReader(keyboardOption);
            Contacts obj = new Contacts();
            System.out.print("Type in your option: ");
            int option = readerOption.read();
            System.out.println(option);
            if(option == 1){
                obj.addContact();
            }
            if(option == 2){
                System.out.println("HI");
                obj.contactList();
            }
            if(option == 3){
                obj.getNumber();
            }
            if(option == 4){
                 obj.removeContact();
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: do you getting any error? if yes then print here

Comment: http://www.asciitable.com/  The character `'2'` has an int value of `50`.  If you want `option` to be a character instead of a number, make it type `char`.

Comment: Why do you have fields `keyboardMethod`/`readerMethod`, then create variables `keyboardOption`/`readerOption` doing the exact same thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FYI: `read()` returns a *character* value, technically a `char`, but it has to be an `int` in order to allow the extra `-1` value for EOF.

[Comment by azurefrog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37233692/my-input-is-coming-different-in-my-program#comment61996863_37233692) is right, the `char` value `'2'` is the numeric ASCII/Unicode value 50.

If you want to read a *number* entered by the user, do this:

```
int option = Integer.parseInt(readerOption.readLine());
```

Beware bad user input.

Answer (score 0):

Andreas is right!

I also know ur intention for ur application!

a while{} loop can solve ur problem!

My English is not skilled ,so I improved ur code!

Change the package's name

```
  package com.fan.component;

 import java.util.HashMap;
 import java.io.*;
 public class Contacts{
 /*Aim:
     *Takes input from the user to add, remove or read a contact's number
     *It also can show you all the contacts the user has added
     *What's more it is finally integrated with IO!! 
  */
 //Initializing some very crucial variables 
 HashMap contacts = new HashMap();
 InputStreamReader keyboardMethod = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
 BufferedReader readerMethod = new BufferedReader(keyboardMethod);
 public void contactList(){
     System.out.println(contacts.entrySet());
 }
  public void addContact() throws IOException{
     System.out.println("Give contacts name");
     //details

        String contactName = readerMethod.readLine();
        String contactNumber= readerMethod.readLine();
        contacts.put(contactName, contactNumber);

 }
 public void removeContact() throws IOException{
     //details
     System.out.println("Give contacts name to remove");
     String contactName = readerMethod.readLine();

     String contactNumber = (String) contacts.get(contactName);
     if(contactName != null)
         contacts.remove(contactNumber);
     else
         System.out.println("No this contact");
 }
 public void getNumber() throws IOException{
     //return 1;
     System.out.println("input contact name");
     String contactName = readerMethod.readLine();
     String contactNum = (String) contacts.get(contactName);
     if(contacts == null)
         System.out.println("No this contact named " + contactName);
     else
         System.out.println(contactName + " : " + contactNum );
 }
 public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException{
     InputStreamReader keyboardOption = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
     BufferedReader readerOption = new BufferedReader(keyboardOption);
     Contacts obj = new Contacts();
     /*
      * added code
      */
     while(true)
     {
         System.out.print("Type in your option: ");
         int option = Integer.parseInt(readerOption.readLine());
         System.out.println(option);
         //add new contact
         if(option == 1){
             obj.addContact();
         }
         //check contact list
         if(option == 2){
             System.out.println("HI");
             obj.contactList();
         }
         //get number
         if(option == 3){
             obj.getNumber();
         }
         //remove contact
         if(option == 4){
             obj.removeContact();
         }
     }

 }
```

}